# como carregar o app.component.ts apenas depois de efetuar o login

Tags: typescript, ionic3

Estou criando um menu para meu aplicativo ionic 3, e me deparei com o seguinte problema: Nesse menu eu trago dados do usuario que vem do banco, esses dados eu carrego no app.component.ts, porém ele busca esses dados antes do cliente logar e da erro pq ainda não tem os dados, e quando eu tiro ele para carregar logo de cara obviamente é necessário dá um refresh no aplicativo para que os dados apareçam no menu, caso contrato fica sem os dados. Queria saber como faço para o o app.component carregar logo após o usuario fazer o login. Obrigado.

Comment: Sua pergunta é estranha, pois, se já chegou a desenvolver o app.component com consulta a banco de dados e tudo mais, logo, vc já deveria saber que precisa de um sistema de login, com geração de token e verificação no banco e tudo mais que um login necessita por ser a porta de entrada da sua aplicação.

Comment: Quem disse que não tem ? acho que você não entendeu a questão, eu fiz o menu depois de criar tudo isso, no app.component eu dou um get nos dados do usuario logado, o problema é que isso só é possível após ele logar, e o que acontece e que ao chegar na página de login o app.component já é carregado e gera um erro na tela dizendo que o id do usuario é nulo, o que realmente é pq ele ainda não logou

Comment: eu queria saber como chamar o app.component apenas depois do usuario efetuar o login, eu fiz um if e coloquei para carregar apenas quando o id não for nulo, o problema é que quando o usuario loga o menu vem vazio e só aparece os dados depois de dar um f5 na tela

Comment: Certo, agora ficou mais claro, então, isso vc tem que definir criando rotas.

Comment: Como funcionaria ? pq percebi que o app.component só é carregado quando o app é aberto ou quando da um update na página

Comment: Cara isso é assunto pra um módulo inteiro de curso, é muito amplo, não tem nem como explanar aqui, depende da estrutura que o app foi feito, da linguagem no back-end e muitas outras questões.

Comment: basicamente se o id for nulo é pq o usuário não está logado certo? então basta direcionar para o login, e isso pode ser feito com as rotas como o @LeAndrade mencionou

Comment: Ricardo isso que é feito, o meu problema é que o menu sempre carrega nulo, entendeu ? o app component só é carregado uma vez quando vc abre o aplicativo, depois só é cerregado se eu dar um update na página, e depois do update os dados aparecem

Comment: Pergunta de baixa qualidade. Adicione informações para ajuda tu.

Comment: Maury, se você perdesse um tempinho olhando a resposta abaixo, veria que já foi resolvido!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Só para deixar registrado como eu fiz para reolver ..

Eu usei o Events do ionic,

Na minha primeira tela que é carregado após o login eu coloquei:

```
ngOnInit():void{
  this.events.publish(configHelper.Events.atualizacaoUserMenu, {});
   let user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(configHelper.storageKeys.user));
   console.log('usuario Logado', user )
}
```

No app.component:

```
private checkEvent(): void{
  this.events.subscribe(configHelper.Events.atualizacaoUserMenu, ()=>{ 
    this.loadUser();
  })
```

Dessa forma sempre que é carregada a primeira página após o login, é feito um publish na app.component, que por sua vez faz um subscribe que carrega as informações do usuário logado para o menu.